# Plotting timestamps with Pandas is not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, ipython

I don't use pandas on a regular basis, so always forget the ins-and-outs.

Normally I would use pandas to plot some some big data like this

```
In[##]: type(data)
Out[##]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In[##]: data
Out[##]: 
                        0          1
0     2015-06-25 00:05:00   9.073205
1     2015-06-25 00:10:00   9.541540
2     2015-06-25 00:15:00   9.835029
3     2015-06-25 00:20:00  10.025486
4     2015-06-25 00:25:00  10.172231
5     2015-06-25 00:30:00  10.290875
6     2015-06-25 00:35:00  10.390787
7     2015-06-25 00:40:00  10.475087
8     2015-06-25 00:45:00   9.881863
9     2015-06-25 00:50:00  10.275264
10    2015-06-25 00:55:00  10.250286
11    2015-06-25 01:00:00  10.037975
12    2015-06-25 01:05:00  10.384542
13    2015-06-25 01:10:00   9.850641
14    2015-06-25 01:15:00  10.297120
15    2015-06-25 01:20:00   9.869374
16    2015-06-25 01:25:00  10.200331
17    2015-06-25 01:30:00  10.103541
18    2015-06-25 01:35:00  10.087930
19    2015-06-25 01:40:00  10.253409
20    2015-06-25 01:45:00  10.009874
21    2015-06-25 01:50:00  10.390787
22    2015-06-25 01:55:00   9.884985
23    2015-06-25 02:00:00  10.334587
24    2015-06-25 02:05:00   9.788196
25    2015-06-25 02:10:00  10.262775
26    2015-06-25 02:15:00   9.863130
27    2015-06-25 02:20:00  10.190964
28    2015-06-25 02:25:00  10.066075
29    2015-06-25 02:30:00  10.094175
...                   ...        ...
22308 2015-10-09 11:11:00   9.900596
22309 2015-10-09 11:16:00  10.078564
22310 2015-10-09 11:21:00  10.215942
22311 2015-10-09 11:26:00  10.325220
22312 2015-10-09 11:31:00  10.422009
22313 2015-10-09 11:36:00  76.063806
22314 2015-10-09 11:41:00  76.063806
22315 2015-10-09 11:46:00  76.063806
22316 2015-10-09 11:51:00  76.063806
22317 2015-10-09 11:56:00  76.063806
22318 2015-10-09 12:01:00  76.063806
22319 2015-10-09 12:06:00  76.063806
22320 2015-10-09 12:11:00  76.063806
22321 2015-10-09 12:16:00  76.063806
22322 2015-10-09 12:21:00  76.063806
22323 2015-10-09 12:26:00  76.063806
22324 2015-10-09 12:31:00  76.063806
22325 2015-10-09 12:36:00  76.063806
22326 2015-10-09 12:41:00  76.063806
22327 2015-10-09 12:46:00  10.056708
22328 2015-10-09 12:51:00   9.906841
22329 2015-10-09 12:56:00  10.184719
22330 2015-10-09 13:01:00  10.156619
22331 2015-10-09 13:06:00  10.062952
22332 2015-10-09 13:11:00  10.322098
22333 2015-10-09 13:16:00   9.953674
22334 2015-10-09 13:21:00  10.272142
22335 2015-10-09 13:26:00   9.963041
22336 2015-10-09 13:31:00  10.153497
22337 2015-10-09 13:36:00  10.212820

[22338 rows x 2 columns]

In [##]: type(data[0][0])
Out[##]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In[##]: data[0][0]
Out[##]: Timestamp('2015-06-25 00:05:00')
```

Now plotting with `data.plot()` gives me:
[image: data.plot()]

Which don't have the dates - I wish to see if there is any gaps in the dates and the data point..

now using `plt.plot(data[0], data[1])` gives me

[image: plt.plot()]

Which is clearly **wrong** since I have no data from Dec 2015 and they seem to be clustered together..

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just add this as a comment but don't have enough rep. Without your data it's hard to check what your final plot would look like using:

```
df['0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['0'])
df = df.set_index('0')
df.plot()
```

Comment: I actually tried to export them by using `to_pickle`, but apparently I have some writing limitations on the PC..

Comment: Could not use the `'`.. so did `data[0] = pd.to_datetime(data[0])` and `data = data.set_index(data[0])` and then `data.plot(). Which makes the x-axis a date line instead of index number (improvement). But I'm still seeing wrong datetime reading - like dec 2015

Comment: Sorry! It is actually working. I just messed it up so I had double dates as index.. Because I was trying @Alexander suggestion. But now it's working. THANK YOU SIR

Comment: Good stuff. The quotes are just if the column names are strings, but in your case they must be ints.